# Algorithm for solving equations whose coefficients are binary

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

Let $A$ be a $d$-dimensional matrix whose entries are 0 or 1.
Is there an efficient or specialized algorithm for solving $A \vec x = \vec 0$?
If so, how many times (complexities) depend on the $d$?

Comment: How about $\vec x = \vec 0$?

Comment: @MathLover wel... I want a nontrivial solution

Comment: What are other constraints/assumptions on $A$ or $\vec x$? Is $A$ square? Then if $A$ is invertible there is no non-trivial solution. If $A$ is not square, there may be trivially many non-trivial solutions if you allow $\vec x$ to be anything, or there may be no non-trivial solution at all.